# Inside IDE(IntelliJ), could not find sbt dependies from External Libraries

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am starting a Scala project and I'm using SBT and Intellij 2020.2.3 as my IDE.

I have the following build.sbt file from [the project](https://github.com/opendiffy/diffy), but I can't seem to get the dependencies in the Idea IDE "External Libraries" section to show up in "libraryDependencies" of SBT after running "sbt update".
The Idea version is that:
[image: IDEA VERSION]

The Idea External Libraies are that:
[image: Idea IDE]

The Sbt libraryDependencies are that:
[image: SBT]

Comment: try invalidate cache/restart

Comment: @RamanMishra it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience , Intellij is very slow to pickup on dependencies and display them.
Bare in mind this is not a reflection on sbt , and asides for the annoyance, you should still be able to sbt compile from the console.
That is the first thing I suggest you test. If you can compile , that means the dependencies were downloaded, are available on the classpath, and its just a matter of getting Intellij to recognize that
You can try one of 2 things, hover over the dependencies in your build.sbt file and you might see a refresh project option , or you can go to module section in project settings and reimport

Comment: Yes, it can compile, but unfortunately neither method works for idea display.